# How to use anchor link in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using ajax to load video in specific div, here is the code

```
  <a id="video-thumb" href="javascript:ajaxpage('/wp-content/themes/naked/ajax/loader.php?id_3', 'video-load');">
   <div id="thumb" style="background:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?= get_field('youtube_video_id_3'); ?>/maxresdefault.jpg) no-repeat">
     <div class="icon"></div>
   </div>
   <span><? echo $title_3 ?></span>
  </a>
```

Video will be load in "Video-load" div, i want to jump the page to this DIV, how can i implement it?

this is the JS (sorry Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to put more code here)

[PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/xbuYJH9g)

Answer (score 0):

index.html :

```
<div id="video-load">

</div>    

<script>

function getVideo()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    var responeText  = xmlhttp.responseText ; // make respone text to variable
    var diPisah =  responeText.split("@") // split respone text each row
    var no = 0;
    var diPilahLagi = [];

        // split and call createVideo function();
        for( no ; no <= ( diPisah.length - 2 ) ; no ++ ){
            diPilahLagi = [];
            diPilahLagi = diPisah[no].split("#");
                createVideo( 
                diPilahLagi[0] , // videoId
                diPilahLagi[1] , // titile
                diPilahLagi[2] , // url
                diPilahLagi[3] );   // youtube Id
        }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","php/siswa/pindai.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("p1=none&p2=none");
}
function createVideo( videoId , title , url , youtubeId ){
   var vidio_thumb   = document.createElement("a");
   vidio_thumb.className = "video-thumb";
   vidio_thumb.id = "video_thumb_" + videoId ;
   vidio_thumb.href = "javascript:ajaxpage('/wp-content/themes/naked/ajax/loader.php?id_3', 'video-load');"

   video-load.appendChild(vidio_thumb);   

   var thumb   = document.createElement("div");
   thumb.id = "thumb_" + videoId;
   thumb.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + '"http://img.youtube.com/vi/' +  youtubeId +  '/maxresdefault.jpg)"' +  "no-repeat";

   vidio_thumb.appendChild(thumb);   

   var icon   = document.createElement("div");
   icon.className = "icon";

   thumb.appendChild(icon);   

   var titleVid   = document.createElement("span");
   titleVid.innerHTML = title ;

   vidio_thumb.appendChild(titleVid);   
}
</script>
```

video.php :

```
<?php

include "../connection.php";


$sql = "select * from `video`";
$jalan = mysql_query($sqlCari);
while( $dataCari = mysql_fetch_array($jalan) ){

    echo $dataCari[0]; // video id 
    echo "#";
    echo $dataCari[1]; // video titile
    echo "#";
    echo $dataCari[1]; // video url
    echo "#";
    echo $dataCari[1]; // video youtube Id
    echo "@";

}
?>
```

and showing the video just call

```
getVideo();
```

Comment: And where is anchor link?

Comment: anchor link is in vidio-load div tag
see function createVidio